# Different results between individual and batch clip of rasters in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, clip

When I cut one raster with `clip raster by mask layer` I get the expected result.

But when applying batch processing with the same vector file, and the same rasters, the rasters aren't clipped and the values are changed to `0` and `NaN`?

The rasters are landsat 5 images, and the vector has the same datum.

Edit: I've figured out this is the gdal command used when processing individually:

`gdalwarp -ot Float32 -q -of GTiff -cutline "some_shape.shp" -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co PREDICTOR=1 -co ZLEVEL=6 -wo OPTIMIZE_SIZE=TRUE "original_raster.tif" "clipped_raster.tif"`

And this one is used in batch processing:

`gdalwarp -ot Byte -q -of GTiff -cutline "some_shape.shp" -co COMPRESS=NONE -wo OPTIMIZE_SIZE=TRUE "original_raster.TIF" "clipped_raster.tif"`

Why the differences?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer was in the gdal command, in the batch processing menu, click on `Toggle advanced mode` and change `Output raster type` to `Float32`. Still don't know why the predetermined option is `Byte`.

Comment: Might be a bug worth reporting at hub.qgis.org.