# QGIS Gdal batch translate

Tags: qgis, gdal-translate

I'm looking to batch convert a number of ascii files to tiff (float 64) using the GDAL translate tool. If I translate a single tile with the tool and choose float 64 the output is a float 64. If I choose float 64 on the parameters then open the batch processing window the resulting tiffs are 8-bit unsigned integer files with a 0-255 range. Where am I going wrong?

The files are Environment agency lidar (DTM):

```
Driver
GDAL provider
AAIGrid
Arc/Info ASCII Grid
Dataset Description
C:\G1\data\NT\NT6203.asc
Band 1
STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=355.612
STATISTICS_MEAN=354.32436956522
STATISTICS_MINIMUM=352.647
STATISTICS_STDDEV=0.94020942067497
Dimensions
X: 500 Y: 500 Bands: 1
Origin
362000,604000
Pixel Size
2,-2
No Data Value
-9999 
Data Type
Float64 - Sixty four bit floating point 
Pyramid overviews
Layer Spatial Reference System
+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +towgs84=446.448,-125.157,542.06,0.15,0.247,0.842,-20.489 +units=m +no_defs
Layer Extent (layer original source projection)
362000.0000000000000000,603000.0000000000000000 :     363000.0000000000000000,604000.0000000000000000
Band
Band 1
Band No
1
Min Val
352.6470000000
Max Val
355.6120000000
Range
2.9650000000
Mean
354.3243695652
Sum of squares
40.6637127174
Standard Deviation
0.9505987904
Sum of all cells
16298.9210000000
Cell Count
46
```

Console code:

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -ot Float64 -outsize 100% 100% -expand rgba -projwin 362000.0 604000.0 363000.0 603000.0 -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co PREDICTOR=1 -co ZLEVEL=6 C:\G1\data\NT\NT6203.asc "[temporary file]"
```

Comment: Could you post some code extracts or screenshots ? Maybe aswell some detailed info on your raster images if possible  ?

Comment: That console code is from the single tile or batch processing? Sometimes there are differences in the arguments passed in batch processing. Like this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/234036/different-results-between-individual-and-batch-clip-of-rasters-in-qgis

Comment: That's really useful adelano - I'll try it and post back tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks aldeano! toggled the advanced options in batch processing and applied the parameters to all the input layers and it worked.